# Changing from SVN to GIT need relevant command for GIT

Tags: git

Below is the command which we are using in SVN to run from script file, now planning to change to GIT from SVN commands. 
Can anyone please let me know relevant command for below SVN command.

```
svn  --username $CVS_USER --password $CVS_PWD diff --diff-cmd=diff -x "-p -U20" FILENAME.txt
```

For commit to GIT below the change i have made for the SVN command. Is it correct?

SVN :

```
svn --username $CVS_USER --password $CVS_PWD commit -F $CM_MSG_FILE --non-interactive --trust-server-cert File1.txt templates/File2.txt
```

GIT :

```
git add File1.txt templates/File2.xml
git commit -m $CM_MSG_FILE 
git push origin BranchName
```

Comment: The first command will have to be `git fetch` or `git pull` (to pull the changes from remote repo to your local repo) and then `git diff` or `git status` to see the changes introduced by others and the changes you are making in the working directory.

Comment: However, such a direct "run one script" approach to migration will probably not work well. For example, your second command will fail in many scenarios (changes not pulled from remote repo to local repo, changes from the remote repo are not merged with the local change). Whoever is doing the commit and push needs to understand git command line or visual tools to address these issues successfully.